# Lift Framework with Eclipse IDE errors

Tags: scala, lift

I am trying out Lift Framework, however I am unable to get it working properly with eclipse.

I get the following error:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.{Handler, Server}
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext
```

object eclipse is not a member of package org on resource: RunWebApp.scala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your classpath is incomplete. How do you import the project in Eclipse? Are you using Sbt and one of the plugins for exporting an Eclipse project?

Check out this tutorial on the Scala IDE website: [Setup and use Lift framework 2.4 in Scala IDE 2.0](http://scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/lift24scalaide20/index.html).